# React props normalization or computed property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

In a datepicker component I want to work with another validated version of a prop.
Example, a datepicker with `ranges` prop, and a `maxDate` prop

```
<DateRangePicker ranges={ranges} maxDate={new Date} />
```

ranges is an array of pairs: `[ [startDate, endDate], ...]`

If a range has an endDate larger then the given `maxDate`, I need to take the minimum of the two. So I need to work with a different (computed) version of the `ranges` props.

I can handle this logic in the component constructor (i.e creating another normalized `ranges` variable), but then if the parent component will change the ranges prop, The datepicker component won't update.

What's the correct way to handle this in react? since there is no option to modify the prop itself, I need a computed normalized version that will bind to the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you [requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53224728/react-props-normalization-or-computed-property/53227925#comment93337111_53224835),

> I still want to know how the component itself can normalize its props

Here is how you can validate/compute the new end date within `DateRangePicker`.

---

You can use [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) to "compute" the end date of each range.

```js
class DateRangePicker extends Component {
  state = { ranges: [] };

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    const ranges = DateRangePicker.getRangesWithinBoundary(nextProps);
    return { ...nextProps, ranges };
  }

  static getRangesWithinBoundary({ ranges, maxDate }) {
    return ranges.map(([startDate, endDate]) => [
      startDate,
      new Date(Math.min.call(null, endDate, maxDate))
    ]);
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

What happens is that,

1. `DateRangePicker` receives a new prop and `getDerivedStateFromProps` is called
2. `getDerivedStateFromProps` computes a new state to apply.
3. `render` uses the computed date range to display

⚠ *Note that `getRangesWithinBoundary` is a helper method to compute the end dates **not** part of React*.

### Code in action

[image: demo in action]

You can see that `endDate` for each range is capped at `maxDate` of `8/1/2018`.

### Working Demo

[image: Edit so.answer.53224728]

Answer (score 0):

you can easily do it inline when passing prop to component,

```
<DateRangePicker ranges = {ranges.map(item=>([item[0], item[1] > maxDate ? maxDate : item[1]]))} maxDate={maxDate} />
```

Comment: I still want to know how the component itself can normalize its props

Comment: You will have to use a lifecycle method like [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) and save derived props in state. But here you can use props without saving them in state, so its better to go that way.

Comment: @user3599803 Which `component` are you referring to? The component using `DateRangePicker`? or within `DateRangePicker` itself?

Comment: @SungKim Of course I'm referring to the child - the DateRangePicker component. In this answer he did the normalization in the parent component

Comment: @user3599803 Please refer to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53227925/4035) above.